# Does using Tor via Whonix protects privacy over public Wifi

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, anonymity, vpn, whonix

I read that to be able to browse anonymously, using only Tor is not sufficient: Your ISP can see that you are on Tor but he cannot see what pages you are visiting because of onion routing.

On the official Whonix page they affirm that their OS protects privacy more than a VPN:
[See the picture HERE](https://www.whonix.org/).
This seems a very adequate solution because whonix is free and opensource while nowadays there is no free VPN.

Suppose a user runs whonix inside virtualBox on a host whose wifi is public (*there is no password to connect to the wifi, you should login with your personal account to access internet*), I am having trouble to see how the user internet traffic is protected.

I mean even if it is encrypted by whonix, isn't it passing through the host and thus the ISP can see the user is on Tor (Tor nodes ips are public...)

Side question: Is using a private wifi (WPA protected) better or is it the same thing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be the same if using a private wifi or a public one, it's because Tor is already ENCRYPTED. This is the obvious reason they created HTTPS

What matters is the fact that anyone can identify you. But the public wifi operator would know that you are using Tor.

The only problem would be if the public wifi operator blocks Tor, but you could use bridges, and also using bridges could prevent the operator to know you are using Tor.

And yes, Whonix is safer than a VPN because many info about your hardware and fingerprints would be anonymized, I'm sure fingerprints would be totally different between host and VM guest.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I indeed need more maturity regarding privacy and Tor. I will look into how bridges work

Comment: Bridges are just private Tor relays that are unlisted from the public, and some of them use mechanisms for preventing an adversary know that you're using Tor.